# hostName in webservice endpoint in mule config?

Tags: mule

I have a mule application which needs to be deployed in different servers. I have question for setting the hostname for HTTP based endpoint address

Should host name come from properties file, replacing it at build time based on the environment for which the application is being built --

```
    Example --
    http:inbound-endpoint address="http://${host.name}:61005/my/service" exchange-pattern="request-response"
```

Or is it possible to build the deployable app with hostname as localhost and replace it at deployment time

```
    Example --
    http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:61005/my/service" exchange-pattern="request-response"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A properties file would work fine but keep in mind Spring's Property Placeholder Resolver can also get values from Java system properties so you could provide a value for `${host.name}` at start-up with:

```
mule -M-Dhost.name=$HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use 0.0.0.0 as the host and it will listen on every network interface of the server:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:61005/my/service" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
```

It means that if, for example, your server has the IP 192.168.0.1, it will automatically server requests at `http://192.168.0.1:61005/my/service/`

It will save you from configuring a deployment file.